# Cloning Html Table Row and Showing DIV Menu

Tags: jquery

I have an HTML table with several rows. If you hover on the row then it displays a contextual menu which allows to add or delete the rows.

When you add the row I clone the existing row and add to the table. This works correctly! The problem is when I hover over the new row it shows the menu at the wrong position. The position is related to the row which I originally cloned! It even return the wrong top and left position which is associated with the original row which was cloned.

Any ideas!

Not sure if this is going to help but here is little bit of code:

```
function addOptionRow(rowToBeAdded,rowId) {

    var searchClass = "TBLCONTENTS";

    var rows = $("#" + rowId).parent().children("tr");
    var rowCount = rows.length;

    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {

        if ($(rows[i]).attr('class') != searchClass && $(rows[i]).prev().attr('class') == searchClass) {

            rowToBeAdded.attr("id", getRandomString()); 
            $(rows[i]).before(rowToBeAdded.clone());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the menu display code:

```
function OnMouseOver(obj) { // obj is row which is passed in

    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;
    var id = "#" + obj.id;   

    currTemplateRow = obj.parentElement.parentElement;

    var pos = $(id).position();
    top = pos.top - 5;
    left = pos.left - 5;

    $("#menuToolsetTemplate").css(
            { position: "absolute",
                top: top + "px",
                left: left + "px"
            }
        ).show();  

}
```

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: There is no code! I think clone makes a very deep copy which also copies the position and everything.

Comment: The positioning error is most likely css related. Are you cloning something like an ID that is then inherited by the images? That would cause inconsistent positioning. Or perhaps the images are dynamically positioned via javascript. If that is the case they are most likely still associated with the parent element.

Comment: I assign a new unique id to add the newly added rows.

Comment: Are you getting the position of the cloned row after adding/appending it to the table?

Comment: Yes after the row has been cloned it is added to the table. Then I hover on the cloned row and it shows the menu at the wrong position.

Comment: I added some code where I add the row to the table.

Comment: Adding row isn't the issue, how is the menu being displayed on hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to simulate what you are doing and it works fine for me.. Check my [jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9hNQU/3/). Onclick on each row it clones that row and appends it to the bottom. [JSBin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/utovis)

As I mentioned in the comment, the obj that is being passed in your function `OnMouseOver(obj)` is not the correct row. You code doesn't tell us where or how this mouse over function is binded to hover(mouseover and mouseout) event.

**JS:**

```
var index = 0;
$('#mytable tr').on ('click', function () {
    var $this_cloned = $(this).clone();
    $this_cloned.attr('id', this.id + (index++));
    $('#mytable tr:last').after($this_cloned);  
});

$('#mytable').on ('mouseenter', 'tr', function () {
    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;
    var id = "#" + this.id;   

    //currTemplateRow = obj.parentElement.parentElement;
    var pos = $(id).position();
    top = pos.top - 5;
    left = pos.left - 5;

    $("#menu").text ('Menu for ' + this.id);

    $("#menu").css(
            { position: "absolute",
                top: top + "px",
                left: left + "px"
            }
        ).show();  
});

$('#mytable').on ('mouseleave', 'tr', function () {
    $("#menu").hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="mytable" cellpadding="0" border="1px" >
    <tr id="row1" >
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2" >
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr id="row3" >
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
        <td>Row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="menu">Menu</div>
```

Comment: The JSFiddle page does not exists! Also, the onMouseOver function in my case is taking the row object. Which is the cloned row and which has the same position as the original row.

Comment: That jsFiddle works for me.. Also onclick on each row it clones that row and appends it to the bottom. I think in your case the mouseover is not taking the correct row object, if it does then the position is going to be on the hovered row.

Comment: You got it right!! The problem was with the image and since I was cloning it was sending the same id of the image where the menu was being displayed. I fixed that and now it works! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking at it from the wrong direction.

- HTML = Structure
- JavaScript = Behavior
- CSS = Design

Don't cross the lines! This is strictly a CSS issue.

You probably have some sort of JavaScript to set the top and left values of the menu dynamically, but since you clone the element, the old position for the menu remains.

What you should do, is **position the parent**, a.k.a. the row, something like this:

```
position: relative;
```

And then, any `position: absolute` element will **relate to the closest positioned parent**.

Then you can have a single consistent style for all context menus.

**[Here's a working example](http://jsbin.com/anenoy/2/edit#preview)**

### The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {

            var $menu = $("<div class=menu>Menu</div>"),                //Create a single menu
                $td;
            $('table tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').append($menu);   //Append it to the first by default, it won't appear until hovered.
            $('table tr').hover(function () {                           //When hovered...
                $td = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)");                  //Find the first table cell in the row
                $('.menu').fadeOut(function () {                        //Fade out the existing menu, and when it ends...
                    $td.append($menu);                                  //Move it to the hovered row
                    $('.menu').fadeIn();                                //Fade it back in
                });

            }, function () { //When going out of hover
                $('.menu', this).fadeOut(); //Fade the menu out.
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table .menu {
            display:    none;
            position:   absolute;
            top:        2px;
            left:       2px;
            background: red;
        }

        table td:nth-child(1) {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
        <td>blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I didn't include the row adding part in this example because it doesn't matter, Just append the `.menu` (or whatever you call it) element to the first `td`, and see that I don't need to recalculate its position (I'm not doing it anywhere). Because it's tied to a positioned parent, (a.k.a., the first TD of the row), it's positioned relatively to that parent.

### Updates:

- Updated code, only one element is created at all times and it is passed between the rows.

Comment: @azamsharp: I've included an example. Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code but I am doing it different way. There is only one menu DIV element on my page. Check out the code above since my function takes the obj (row) as the onMouseOver parameter.

Comment: That's also possible. If you append an existing node to an element, it would remove it from its original position, and place it in the new.