# Show a Menu in Table Last Row (Link) and Display a Modal Window on click on menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've refereed the below article,
[Cloning Html Table Row and Showing DIV Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219050/cloning-html-table-row-and-showing-div-menu)
http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9hNQU/3/

I've similar requirement, but pretty new to these technologies..!
My requirement is, i'll have a Hyper link at the end of each row, now on click/hover -> i want to show a pulldown/dropdown menu -> user can select any of the option from the menu items -> and that should show me a modal window with some form or data (coming from back end systems) which is specific to the selected row!

For ex: I want to modify one of the rows content, and i will click on hyper link at the end of the row, that should take me to modal window, and there i should be able to change and save and close the modal window!

I've made changes to the above code like,
in html:

```
<td id="mytd1"><a href="">Row 1</a></td>
```

in js:

```
$('#mytable').on ('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
    var top = 0;
    var left = 0;
    var id = "#" + this.id;   

    //currTemplateRow = obj.parentElement.parentElement;
    var pos = $(id).position();
    top = pos.top - 5;
    left = pos.left - 5;

    $("#menu").text ('Menu for TD ' + this.id); 

    $("#menu").css(
            { position: "absolute",
                top: top + "px",
                left: left + "px"
            }
        ).show();  
});

$('#mytable').on ('mouseleave', 'td', function () {
    $("#menu").hide();
});
```

this works on hover on last row (Row3), but i should be able to show menu and onclick on menu item i want to show modal window!

Please refer me if there are any articles/threads similar to my requirements..help me to resolve this issue!

tnx, saps

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#mytable').on ('mouseenter', 'td', function () {
var top = 0;
var left = 0;
var id = "#" + this.id;   

//currTemplateRow = obj.parentElement.parentElement;
var pos = $(id).position();
top = pos.top - 5;
left = pos.left - 5;

$("#menu").text ('Menu for TD ' + this.id); 

$("#menu").css(
        { position: "absolute",
            top: top + "px",
            left: left + "px"
        }
    ).show(); 
//list of menu item  
// modal-form content for modal
  $("menu-item").click(function(){
      $('<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">' + modalform + '</div>').modal().on('shown', function ()
            {  
                //callback function
                 return false;
             });
});
});

$('#mytable').on ('mouseleave', 'td', function () {
    $("#menu").hide();
 });
```

Comment: when i've tested the code in http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9hNQU/3/ .. nothing displayed..! do i need to add any html content too?

Comment: u have to include modal css and js

Comment: But i've below issues: 1) when i click on edit it should show 3 links, but it repeats and the last one only shows 3 link 2) when i click on first link, the dialog opens, but i want the selected table row (index) details on the dialog box 3) same as point.2, the moment i click on edit record link, the selected table row's index VALUE should be passed to modal window!

Comment: please help on the above issues!

Comment: give different id to link then use these id to identify edit comment and save-update accordingly